# How to set a timeout during remote ejb lookup?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi

I'm trying to access a remote ejb which is not available yet. But the lookup takes 5 min before I get the NameNotFoundException. Is there a way I can set the lookup timeout to a lesser value so that the client application doesn't hang for 5 mins? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What application server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Do the lookup in another thread, so that the client GUI does not hang. You can use plain Runnable to do this, or try a better option like [swingworker](https://swingworker.dev.java.net/).

To customize the JNDI lookup timeout, I am afraid, you will have to hack the internals of an open source app server, if that is an option.

Comment: Thanks a lot Swapnonil. I'm using jboss so I was able to specify lookup timeouts in there. That worked :)